# ¿Que significa #<numero_cualquiera> al final de stdClass en un var_dump de objeto en PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Teniendo esta consulta a la base de datos, configurando para obtener un objeto:

```
$data = [
    123 => 1000,
    5 =>  20000,
    9 =>  30000,
];
$id = 123;
$news = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM personas')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($news);
```

El `var_dump` regresa esto:

```
array(2) 
{ 
     [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) 
     { 
        ["nombre"]=> string(4) "saul" 
        ["cedula"]=> int(23777344) 
        ["genero"]=> int(0) 
     } 

     [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) 
     { 
        ["nombre"]=> string(6) "victor" 
        ["cedula"]=> int(25171681) 
        ["genero"]=> int(0) 
     } 
}
```

Mi pregunta era: ¿Que significa ese #3 y #4 al lado de cada objeto?:

```
object(stdClass)#3
object(stdClass)#4
```

Leyendo en php.net encontre esto:

```
 $obj3 = (object)[]; // Cast empty array to object
 object(stdClass)#3 (0) {}
```

Es como una conversión, pero no aparece el `#4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomado de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-hav):

> Es una referencia interna a la instancia del objeto, es el identificador del objeto escrito en decimal.

Referencia: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/var.c#L155

```
php_printf("%sobject(%s)#%d (%d) {\n", COMMON, class_name, Z_OBJ_HANDLE_PP(struc), myht ? zend_hash_num_elements(myht) : 0);
```

Comment: **Complementando eso:** leyendo en php.net cuando se usa ```fetch_obj```, se devuelve la siguiente fila como un objeto anónimo con nombres de columna como propiedades, y un objeto anonimo es clase ```#3```